# How to replace java xml header content using XML_Transform in logic app?

Tags: xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have simple logic app with `Transform_XML` in which i'm giving input as `java xml` data.

I want to replace a below string from that input `java xml`.

```
'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>'
to
'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
```

I tried using following into code view but its not working any clue ?

```
 "Transform_XML": {
                "inputs": {
                                       "content": "@{xml(replace(string(triggerBody()),'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>','<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>'))}",

                    "integrationAccount": {
                        "map": {
                            "name": "mytestmap"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Xslt"
            }
```

But at `Xml Validation` it is giving error -

> InvalidXml. The provided content must be of XML content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace() looks correct, but you probably don't need to use xml() at this point.

If the content from the Trigger is coming in as base64, you may need to do a **base64ToString()** first as replace() may be trying to act on the base64 content instead.  Some Actions handle this correctly, other don't.

replace(base64ToString(triggerBody()),'',''))}"

But...be very careful changing the header like this since now you're obligated to send it as full UTF to any downstream clients.

Comment: Is there any good way to do so? I want to change urf value and pass XML to XML transform. Thanks

Comment: And if I don't use xml the content is only - replace(triggerBody(),'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>','<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>')) inside as input to step xml transform.

Comment: @Neo Good way to...?  If you're invoking an Xsl Transform, you really shouldn't need to change the declaration, the transform engine works with both.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: When I use utf 16 it gives error said xml is not in correct format and for utf 8 it works perfect that's why I want to change utf value

Comment: @Neo I don't understand, why are you trying to change it *to* 16 then?  It's most likely UTF-8 anyway by default.

Comment: I got the input file with utf=16 which does not work , to make it work i have to change value utf=8.

Comment: Look at the run history to see of the body is coming through as plain text or base64 encoded.  You may have to base64ToString() first.  Some Actions auto-handle this, some don't.

Comment: error -
InvalidXml. The provided content must be of XML content type.

Comment: @Neo No, I mean look at the Run History to see exactly what the content coming out of the trigger is.

Comment: history shows encoded format data and giving error also `"InvalidXml. The provided content must be of XML content type."`

Comment: yes its base 64 , strange why it is giving an error.